Studs above fireplace 20” apart; can I attach a large piece of wood on the wall there & mount things to the wood?
I’m doing the cardinal sin of mounting my TV above the fireplace, BUT I bought a motorized mount that lowers the tv down to an ergonomic/comfortable height. We also don’t use the fireplace so there isn’t any concern of the heat damaging the tv. Now that that’s out of the way: this mount can only attach to studs that are up to 18” apart, and we seem to only have 2 studs 20” apart there.
Would it be feasible for me to screw a largepiece of wood like plywood or something to the studs, and attach the mount to that wood? I could “finish” the wood in a way that it wouldn’t look horrific, but I’m also not super concerned because the TV would hide it when the tv is stowed anyway.

You don't use the fireplace and you are going to put the TV in front of it. Set it on the floor in front of it and skip the whole motorized mount foolishness. Show videos of fires in fireplaces when you are not watching other things on the TV.

@Ecnerwal: That may be a bit lower than ideal, but it's a valid frame challenge. I am seriously considering designing a mock fireplace for my library as a way to make a large screen fit the aesthetic I want for the room.
